# Tastypie list endpoints added using prepend_urls

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am trying to figure out how to show all endpoints from an API I've written. In browsing to the root of the API, I see a list of resources and a single get endpoint. How do I generate a list to show all endpoints? I tried django-tastypie-swagger but had the same results. It only listed a few GET methods for each resource and didn't show all the prepend_urls that I added to the resource. Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

I have some helper methods in the get_manufacturer_wedges to help with the response. Side note, I'm very new to python and this whole stack. I come from a c#.net background. I am building a golf app.

```
class ManufacturerResource(BaseMongoResource):

    class Meta:
        max_limit = 0
        queryset = Manufacturer.objects.all().order_by('id')
        allowed_methods = ('get')
        resource_name = 'manufacturers'
        include_resource_uri = False

    def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>[\w\d_.-]+)/wedges/$" % self._meta.resource_name,
            self.wrap_view('get_manufacturer_wedges'), name="api_get_manufacturer_wedges"),
    ]

    def get_manufacturer_wedges(self, request, **kwargs):
        prim_key = kwargs['pk'] + "|Wedge"
        wedges = Club.objects(_id__startswith=prim_key).order_by('name')
        return self.create_response(request, HelperMethods.obj_to_list(wedges))
```

Here is the output when I go to the root of the api (/api/v1/):

```
{
  "file_upload" : {
    "schema" : "/api/v1/file_upload/schema/",
    "list_endpoint" : "/api/v1/file_upload/"
  },
  "members" : {
    "schema" : "/api/v1/members/schema/",
    "list_endpoint" : "/api/v1/members/"
  },
  "manufacturers" : {
    "schema" : "/api/v1/manufacturers/schema/",
    "list_endpoint" : "/api/v1/manufacturers/"
  },
  "courses" : {
    "schema" : "/api/v1/courses/schema/",
    "list_endpoint" : "/api/v1/courses/"
  },
  "clubs" : {
    "schema" : "/api/v1/clubs/schema/",
    "list_endpoint" : "/api/v1/clubs/"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code you could show?

Comment: @Joel I have added some source. There are a few more endpoints in the prepend_urls, but I just removed them since they are all written the same just using different verbs ("Driver", "Putter", etc). Granted, these endpoints do work and function just fine when I call them, but I am wanting to create some type of documentation for them. So spitting out all the routes will suffice. Thanks!